# Get all users who has specific permissions for a post (Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-nova

I have the following tables:

```
user
  - id
  - name

model_has_permission
  - permission_id
  - model_type
  - model_id

permissions
  - id
  - name

post
  - id
  - title
  - content
```

I am using Laravel 10.x with the laravel-permissions package.

Now I want to create a function in my **\App\Models\Post** class called **users().**
This function should give me all users, who have a specific permission called 'post.<id>.read'.

I am a bit confused when it comes to the different relationships so I am trying my luck here.

I tried to use morphToMany but with no success.

Comment: help please :-(